# RoR 3.2.8: Is there an HTML5 combobox helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

Right now, I'm using the `form_for.select` and `options_for_select` rails helpers to create a select box with the data from the model. However, what I really need is a combobox like the one introduced with HTML5:

```html
<input type=text list=browsers >
<datalist id=browsers >
   <option> Google
   <option> IE9
</datalist>
```

Is there a rails helper for creating such elements?

Comment: Wait a second on a second glance, that doesn't look like valid HTML, are you sure thats right?

Comment: @CyleHunter W3C says its valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but it's quite easy to setup your own form builder helper method to achieve such a result, a simple example would be:

**app/form_builders/combobox_form_builder.rb**

```
 class ComboboxFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Context # for nested content_tag
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper #for sanitize_to_id method access

  def combobox_tag(name, options, opts= {})
     @template.content_tag(:input, :name => name, :id => sanitize_to_id(name), :type => "text", :list => opts[:list_id]) do
       content_tag(:datalist, :id => opts[:list_id]) {options}
     end    
  end    
end
```

After restarting your server you can implement your new combobox using the form builder by specifying a builder argument in your form_for call:

```
<%= form_for @foo, builder: ComboboxFormBuilder do |f| %>
    <%= f.combobox_tag(:browser, options_for_select(["Firefox", "Chrome", "IE9"]), :list_id => "list")%>
<% end %>
```

Output HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="browser" list="list" id="browser">
<datalist id="list">
  <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
  <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
  <option value="IE9">IE9</option>
</datalist>
```

**Keep in mind that both IE & Safari do not offer support for the HTML5 Datalist.**

Comment: didn't knew it could be so simple, let me give it a try.

Comment: How can i pass the form and model parameters? as when you build a form_for.field it knows how to construct the name and id

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238798/adding-a-method-to-formbuilder-that-calls-a-helper-method-that-renders-a-partial You need to either create your own FormBuilder subclass and use that, or you can monkey-patch FormBuilder using Ruby's metaprogramming. I'm pretty sure the former is the preferred way of doing it, but both should work. You could override form_for in your app to use your new FormBuilder instead of the default one, so you don't need a lot of code changing.

Comment: Updated again for clarity, the above should cover pretty much everything you need. If you want to extend your combobox tag further to better emulate other form builder helper methods see [form tag helpers](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers) for ref.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, list: 'first-name' %>
  <datalist id="first-name">
    <% Person.all.each do |person| %>
      <option value="<%= person.first_name %>"></option>
    <% end %>
  </datalist>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You may also want to do distinct:

`<% Person.select(:first_name).distinct.each do |person| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Just example from my code:

```
= form_tag controller:'beer', action: 'create' do
  = text_field :beer, :name, list: 'beer-name'
  %datalist#beer-name
    - Beer.all.each do |beer|
      %option{value: beer.name}
```